# Laravel nova how to hook create method logic to pass default data without showing that field in form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-nova

How can I pass default value in resource field without showing that field in form while creating and updating?

I know I can use `withMeta(['value' => '1'])` to pass default value but it will won't work if field is not visible on form.

also, I know that in the model I can use `$attribute` variable to pass default value but I only want to pass the default value if resource created is from nova.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with a combination of these two packages:

- https://github.com/inspheric/nova-defaultable-fields
- https://github.com/MohmmedAshraf/nova-hidden-field

For example:

`Text::make('Email From')
    ->default(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS')),`

and

`HiddenField::make('created_by_id')
  ->hideFromDetail()
  ->hideFromIndex()
  ->default(Auth::user()->id),`